# Toggle button in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

A bit of a newbie, to using Xamarin forms and I was wondering if there is a way to create the toggle button in the image below in Xamarin forms and that is works on both platforms (Android and iOS).

[image]

Would the only way, to achieve this require me to import the material design library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could install the plugin  [Plugin.SegmentedControl](https://github.com/1iveowl/Plugin.SegmentedControl) from nuget .

iOS
Add initializer to AppDelegate

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
{
    global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();

    Plugin.Segmented.Control.iOS.SegmentedControlRenderer.Initialize();
    ...
}
```

#### Usage

```
<control:SegmentedControl 
                x:Name="SegmentedControl" 
                SelectedSegment="{Binding SelectedSegment, Mode=TwoWay}"
                TintColor="BlueViolet"
                SelectedTextColor="White"
                DisabledColor="Gray"
                BorderColor="Black"
                BorderWidth="2.0"
                FontSize="Small"
                FontFamily="{StaticResource PlatformFontName}"
                Margin="8,8,8,8"
                SegmentSelectedCommand="{Binding SegmentChangedCommand}"
                OnElementChildrenChanging="OnElementChildrenChanging"
                ItemsSource="{Binding SegmentStringSource}">
                <!--<control:SegmentedControl.Children>
                    <control:SegmentedControlOption Text="{Binding ChangeText}"/>
                    <control:SegmentedControlOption Text="Item 2"/>
                    <control:SegmentedControlOption Text="Item 3"/>
                    <control:SegmentedControlOption Text="Item 4"/>
                </control:SegmentedControl.Children>-->
            </control:SegmentedControl>
```

Comment: Zhang is there a way of changing the orientation of the items in the plugin above. I have been looking at the documentation and there does not seem to be that option. I am trying to create a vertical toggle group as well.